# Regular expression for finding embedded javascript urls

Tags: regex, python-3.x

First of all, sorry for the question name. Regex problems are hard to name.

I'm building a program for code-reviewing javascript files. The approach is black-box, so all we get is the html code from a web page for example.

The idea is to find all the javascript files present in the code and then analyzing them with some tool.

Im having some issues with finding the javascript files, mainly because each webpage is sort of different so something that works for every webpage is complicated.

I have found the following problems with solutions.

Case I

```
text = '"somenameforafile.js"'
js_found = re.findall('"(.+?).js"', text)
```

Case II

```
text = '"https://somenameforafile.js"'
js_found_2 = re.findall('"https://(.+?).js"',get_text)
```

In case II I can catch things like `s3.amazonaws.bucketname` with some further filtering

The problem is that Im finding things like the following (js is at the end):

```
setTimeout(ld,100)}a.P(1);var j="appendChild",h="createElement",k="src",n=d[h]("div"),v=n[j](d[h](z)),b=d[h]("iframe"),g="document",e="domain",o;n.style.display="none";m.insertBefore(n,m.firstChild).id=z;b.frameBorder="0";b.id=z+"-loader";if(/MSIE[ ]+6/.test(navigator.userAgent)){b.src="javascript:false"}b.allowTransparency="true";v[j](b);try{b.contentWindow[g].open()}catch(w){c[e]=d[e];o="javascript:var d="+g+".open();d.domain='"+d.domain+"';";b[k]=o+"void(0);"}try{var t=b.contentWindow[g];t.write(p());t.close()}catch(x){b[k]=o+'d.write("'+p().replace(/"/g,String.fromCharCode(92)+'"')+'");d.close();'}a.P(2)};ld()};nt()})({loader: "static.olark.com/jsclient/loader0.js",name:"olark",methods:["configure","extend","declare","identify"]});

Expected Output:
static.olark.com/jsclient/loader.js
```

Which could go into approach I, problem is I get basically all the text with that approach. Is it there any easy way to get urls embedded so much into random text?

Comment: So what are you looking to extract, just the file name?

Comment: The obvious thing to do is change `.+` to use a character class which only matches characters allowed in URLs (i.e. not `"`, for example). A different approach would be to open the page in a browser (see Selenium for automation) and capture the URLs it makes requests to.

Comment: @ctwheels Im trying to get the javascript url so I can see the code in it

Comment: @kaya3 I'll look into it! Im not that experienced at regex yet. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can exclude the `"` form the match using a negated character class `([^\s"]+)\.js\b` https://regex101.com/r/e2iKBt/1 Note to escape the dot to match it literally.

Comment: @Manuel, sorry, it's not exactly clear - could you provide us multiple inputs and their expected outputs?

Comment: Ill update the question, what was suggested by @kaya3 and The Fourth Bird was what I was looking for, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negated character class `[^\s"]+` to match 1 or more times not a whitespace char or a double quote and capture that in group 1.

Then match the js part `\.js\b` by escaping the dot and add a word boundary after js to prevent is being part of a larger word.

```
([^\s"]+)\.js\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e2iKBt/1)